# WPF MVVM Event Notification from User Control to Window

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm

I have a window control that contains four user controls (screens) in a wizard style environment.  (i.e. only one user control will be viewable at all times)  The window control has a series of buttons that act as the primary navigation between all the user controls.

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
|        SCREEN x of 4           |
|                                |
----------------------------------
|                                |
|        Back   Next    Cancel   |
----------------------------------
```

The wizard will build a profile of information as the user completes each screen.  I have defined a Profile type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` that will contain the information the user provides.  So far, so good.

My question is:  When the first user control (Screen 1 of 4) modifies the Profile type, how do I alert the Window?  I'm trying to use MVVM and not use code-behind.

I tried setting up an event on the first user control.  The window would be the subscriber to that event, but that's not working.

Is there a better approach for a user control to alert the main window that something has happened?

Comment: Based upon what you wrote, the 'golden' standard is to bind the various buttons to commands in your view-model.  Once the relevant command is executed, the view-model can use the event aggregator to broadcast the info to all interested components.

Answer (score 0):

What MVVM framework are you using? Most of them have an implementation of the `Mediator` pattern to handle communication between view models.

I use Cinch V2 and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38278/WPF-If-Carlsberg-did-MVVM-Frameworks-Part-2-of-n#MediatorMessaging) you can find an explanation of how it implements the pattern and also see some code showing how to use it.

If you are not using a specific MVVM framework take the ideas from the implementation above and apply to you code!

Comment: I'm not currently using an MVVM framework.  But I think you've given me a direction to go in.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM uses Commands instead of Click handlers. So you should have an implementation of `ICommand` interface ready to use or you can get it from any [MVVM oriented Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using)

If you want to keep things simple, here is the link [how to use commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2010/06/24/simplifying-commands-in-mvvm-and-wpf.aspx)